# How do I access a non static variable from a script thats attached to a canvas from another script in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made a game where the player has three lives. The lives are created in a script called Score which is attached to a canvas so the hearts appear on the screen. A "public static int health" is created in the same script to keep track of the lives. If this variable is static the lives refill when a player changes level, which I don't want. However, if the variable isn't static I can't access it from another script using "Score.health". The other script I'm trying to access the lives from is called Jump and it's attached to the player to see if it collides with anything and remove lives.

I have tried using "GameObject.Find("Gamecanvas").GetComponent<.Score>().health -= 1;" to access it from the jump script but it doesn't work. I've also tried the don't destroy on load and having the health variable static. (Ignore the . before Score it didn't show up else)
So in conclusion I either need a way to access the non static variable health from the Jump script or need a way to have the lives not refill while changing levels(while health is static)

Comment: what has a "Score"-component to do with a `Life`? Seems like you have some broken design. I suppose you should make lifes a property within your player-class

Comment: The score script stores both the player's score and the lives since they both appear on the screen by using the canvas, it would probably been smarter to store the lives in the player's script but then I wasn't sure how to make it appear on the canvas from the canvas script(Score) :(

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend making the `Health` variable static and public. What I would do is the following:

1. Put the `Health` variable in the player class because that makes more sense. You should probably make it private and then just expose a getter like this: `public int Health { get; private set; }`. This way other unauthorized scripts will not be able to change the player's health.
2. In the `Score` script create a serialized reference to the player script like so: `[SerializeField] private Player player`.
3. In the inspector drag the player object to this player reference box
4. Change the UI according to the player health. You can access it with `player.Health`

This might not be the best design choice but it will get you going for a while.
Hope this helps.